# How do I read these IRS SOI Tables for Individual Income?

Tags: usa, income, irs

Has anyone worked with the [IRS SOI Tables for Individuals](https://www.irs.gov/uac/soi-tax-stats-individual-statistical-tables-by-size-of-adjusted-gross-income)?

I am doing research on income distribution, and while these resources in particular the series: `All Returns:  Sources of Income, Adjustments Deductions and Exemptions, and Tax Items` looks good, I can't find much support explaining the breakdown for the items.

My particular interest is in [Table 1.4](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-soi/12in14ar.xls) the 2012 table for Sources of Income. Inside is a breakdown of income ranges, individual types of income, types of deductions, and net gains/losses. I am interested in knowing the breakdown for `Adjusted gross income less deficit` (Item 2, Column C) and the breakdown for `Total income` (Item 4, Column E).

If I am reading this document correctly, some combination of Columns F through EG by addition/subtraction should equal the Total Income and Adjusted Gross Income for each row (within a margin of rounding error). Does anyone know which items I should be using?

Sidenote: The reason I am choosing the year 2012 is because it coincides with the observed year for the 2013 Survey of Consumer Finances. I want to compare the source of income by income level between surveys such as the SCF, CPS ASEC, ACS, and others with administrative data such as these IRS SOI tables.